# Can any dragon be an alpha?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

As shown in the films, dragons like "bewilderbeast" and "Seadragonus Giganticus Maximus" are alpha dragons by nature.

But it also showed the transformation of a night fury into alpha, so for this and the capacity for transformation that can be made in the game for mobile, I pose several questions...

Can any dragon become alpha? If so, what are the requirements that are needed to adquire this transformation?

Can there be certain alphas "by species"? For example an alpha between the "nocturnal fury's" and a "bewilderbeast" above this.

Comment: Interesting. Makes me also wonder about the real life equivalents e.g. dog breeds: could an unusually badass Chihuahua challenge and usurp a bigger alpha hound and lead a pack of dogs that were all 10 times its size?

Comment: Yes is exactly my problem, i don't know if the size is a real problem here...

Comment: I guess, any dragon strong-willed and powerful enough to beat old alpha could become new one, not that there would be many of such guys.

Comment: Are you limiting your canon to the movies, or are you considering the original book series?  I.e. the answer might be different between the two.

Comment: @Mithoron if any dragon can why doesn't exist more alpha dragons in the films?

Answer (score 3):

A Bewilderbeast is an alpha by nature, probably through heirs like our modern monarchy. However, in HTTYD 2 we see Toothless take the transformation into an alpha. Toothless is probably able to become the alpha because he defeated the current alpha, displaying courage and nobility. Evidence from https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Alpha_Dragon

> The position of Alpha can change in dragons, usually through a fight to the death. The Alpha has been seen providing food and protection for other dragons. Because the role of Alpha is won by combat, it seems very likely that Alphas are almost always massive dragons, with Toothless being an incredibly unlikely case.

Toothless was probably only able to become the Alpha because of his superior ability.

Comment: This would appear to be a nice answer but would be improved if you could [edit] in any evidence you may have such as quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that any dragon can be an alpha, but to become the alpha they have to go through the required challenges such as defeating the current alpha. It is just like a pack of wolves or lions and such.

Comment: Could you [edit] in any evidence that led you to believe this?

Comment: Also, that's not really how wolf packs work.  Most wolf packs are family units, with the "alphas" being the parental units.